# MySQL Syntax Error in Create Table Statement

Tags: mysql, create-table

I'm not that great at SQL statements, sorry, I have a statement:

```
CREATE TABLE app (  
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  
    attachments LONGTEXT,  
    cc TEXT,  
    cc_full TEXT,  
    date TEXT NOT NULL,  
    from TEXT,  
    from_full TEXT NOT NULL,  
    headers TEXT NOT NULL,  
    html_body LONGTEXT,  
    mailbox_hash TEXT NOT NULL,  
    message_id TEXT NOT NULL,  
    reply_to TEXT,  
    subject TEXT NOT NULL,  
    tag TEXT,  
    text_body LONGTEXT,  
    to TEXT,  
    to_full TEXT NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
)
```

Unfortunately, I receive this error :

> error (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'from TEXT, from_full TEXT NOT NULL, headers TEXT NOT NULL, html_body LONGTEXT, m' at line 1

I thought it might be the '`from`' being a reserved words problem so I wrapped all my column names in quotes too, but still no joy!

Please help!

Comment: @Sashi if you read the question properly, the error message is in the question.

Comment: Thank you all, I was using double quotes to escape the reserved words rather than the back tick. Thank you again, all!

Comment: Just to add, "date", although a reserved word, does not need to be escaped (see: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) as it is permitted although I am sure it is best practice to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FROM is a reserved MySQL keyword. Change your fieldname to something else.
Same thing with your `date` and `to`fields.

Comment: If you read the question properly, he has already taken from into account

Answer (score 3):

`date` and `from` are reserved words in any SQL format.
Always use back quotes( **`** ), to surround them, to get them accepted.

Refer: [MysQL Reserved Words](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/reserved-words.html)